# $F(t)=(\beta/\alpha)\int_{0}^{t}\frac{(t/\alpha)^{\beta-1}}{[1+(t/\alpha)^{\beta}]^2}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, definite-integrals

Compute

$$F(t)=(\beta/\alpha)\int_{0}^{t}\frac{(t/\alpha)^{\beta-1}}{[1+(t/\alpha)^{\beta}]^2}dt$$

#### My Attempt :

Let $u=(t/\alpha)\Rightarrow \alpha du=dt$

so,

$$F(t)=(\beta/\alpha)\int_{0}^{(t/\alpha)}\frac{u^{\beta-1}}{[1+u^{\beta}]^2}\alpha du$$

$$=\beta\int_{0}^{(t/\alpha)}\frac{u^{\beta-1}}{[1+u^{\beta}]^2} du$$

Then i've been stumbled .

Comment: Did you try $z = 1 + u^{\beta}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the process started by the proposer the integral
\begin{align}
F(u)= \frac{\beta}{\alpha} \, \int_{0}^{u} \frac{\left(\frac{t}{\alpha}\right)^{\beta-1}}{\left[ 1 + \left( \frac{t}{\alpha} \right)^{\beta} \right]^{2}}dt
\end{align}
can be reduced by making the substitution $x = \frac{t}{\alpha}$ for which
\begin{align}
F(u) = \beta \, \int_{0}^{u/\alpha} \frac{x^{\beta -1}}{(1 + x^{\beta})^{2}} 
dx
\end{align}
Now making the substitution $y = x^{\beta}$, $dy = \beta \, x^{\beta-1} \, dx$, the integral becomes
\begin{align}
F(u) &= \int_{0}^{(u/\alpha)^{\beta}} \frac{dy}{(1+y)^{2}} \\
&= \left[ \frac{-1}{1+y} \right]_{0}^{(u/\alpha)^{\beta}} 
= 1 - \frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{u}{\alpha} \right)^{\beta}} 
= \frac{\left( \frac{u}{\alpha} \right)^{\beta}}{1 + \left( \frac{u}{\alpha} \right)^{\beta}} 
= \frac{u^{\beta}}{\alpha^{\beta} + u^{\beta}}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Simply substitute $v=1+u^\beta$. Then $dv = \beta u ^{\beta -1} du.$ The integral then works out nicely.

Comment: Please check. Perhaps your substitution produce $1/0=\infty$